# Open hover menu after hovering on logo

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Wassup Guys,

I am building a web page with Laravel for a friend of mine. I created a hover menu with sub-menu labels. At the current moment the menu opens after clicking on the logo (.gif animation). How can I change my code in order, so that hovering over the logo extends / opens the actual hover menu? Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="header.png">


    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">


    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html{
            background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/2f/b6/902fb683da6e99129aa43990f81607cd.gif');
        }

        .exactCenter {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 15%;
            left:51%;
            margin-top: -100px;
            margin-left: -100px;
        }
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,700,800);

*,html,body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,label,fieldset,input,p,blockquote,th,td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

article,aside,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section {
    display: block;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
    color: #BA0707;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #BA0707;
}


nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.menu {
    display: block;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.menu li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.menu li a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover,.menu li:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #9ca3da;
}

.menu ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: translate(0,20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu ul:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    color: #797979;
    background: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a:hover,.menu ul li:hover>a {
    background: #9ca3da;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}

.menu ul ul {
    left: 149px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(20px,20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu ul ul:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 10%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.menu li>ul ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}

.responsive-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    background: #374147;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.responsive-menu:hover {
    background: #374147;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.homer {
    background: #9ca3da;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .mainWrap {
        width: 768px;
    }

    .menu ul {
        top: 37px;
    }

    .menu li a {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    a.homer {
        background: #374147;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mainWrap {
        width: auto;
        padding: 50px 20px;
    }

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .responsive-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    nav {
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
    }

    .menu li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .menu li a {
        background: #fff;
        color: #797979;
    }

    .menu li a:hover,.menu li:hover>a {
        background: #9ca3da;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .menu ul {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transform: initial;
    }

    .menu li:hover>ul {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        position: relative;
        transform: initial;
    }

    .menu ul ul {
        left: 0;
        transform: initial;
    }

    .menu li>ul ul:hover {
        transform: initial;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
}
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:none;
} </style>
    <script>
        function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('centered')) {

                if (document.getElementById('centered').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('centered').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('centered').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="exactCenter" onclick="switchVisible();"><img src="log.gif" ></div>

    <div class="centered" id="centered">
    <nav>
<a id="resp-menu" class="responsive-menu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i> Menu</a>    
   <ul class="menu">
   <li><a class="homer" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 5</a></li>   
   </ul>
   </li>
  <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> PORTFOLIO</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i> CATEGORIES</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
     <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> SITEMAP</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `onmouseover()` instead of onClick?

Comment: There are too much code just for a simple hover question. Please, try to remove the unnecessary code from the snippet so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Change (onclick)

```
<div class="exactCenter" onclick="switchVisible();"><img src="log.gif" ></div>
```

To (onmouseover):

```
<div class="exactCenter" onmouseover="switchVisible();"><img src="log.gif" ></div>
```

`onmouseover` is Javascript equivalent of `hover`.